# Mixins in django.?

Tags: python, django, mixins

Django’s built-in class-based views provide a lot of functionality, but some of it you may want to use separately. For instance, you may want to write a view that renders a template to make the HTTP response, but you can’t use TemplateView; perhaps you need to render a template only on POST, with GET doing something else entirely. While you could use TemplateResponse directly, this will likely result in duplicate code.

For this reason, Django also provides a number of mixins that provide more discrete functionality. Template rendering, for instance, is encapsulated in the TemplateResponseMixin. The Django reference documentation contains

```
class AuthorDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Author

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = AuthorInterestForm()
        return context


class AuthorInterestFormView(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "books/author_detail.html"
    form_class = AuthorInterestForm
    model = Author

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("author-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk})

class AuthorView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = AuthorDetailView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = AuthorInterestFormView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

> Please someone explian me,with simple example...

Answer (score 0):

The code and the paragraph provided in the question are from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#a-better-solution), in case useful for someone reading the question.

#### A simple mixin example

If a mixin adds methods and attributes to your class, a simple mixin could be one that adds only one method:

```
# views.py
class AddHelloToContextMixin:
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["hello"] = "Hello World!"
        return context
```

Notice the line `context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)`, which is calling the method from the parent class, so the method from the parent class will fill the `context` variable with a dictionary, and we add the key-value pair `"hello" : "Hello World!"` as an extra addition to that context.

The reason why we are naming that method `get_context_data` is because we want to overwrite the method of [ContextMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2/django/views/generic/base.py#L21), which is used in many generic views. As an example, check [TemplateView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.2/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/), [ListView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) and [FormView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) at [Classy Class-Based Views](https://ccbv.co.uk/): there, if you click "Hierarchy Diagram", you can see that `ContextMixin` is being inherited in all of them.

If we were using this `AddHelloToContextMixin` with a `TemplateView` it would look like this:

```py
# views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class MyView(AddHelloToContextMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "my_template.html"
```

Then you could access the value `"Hello World!"` in your template like this:

```html
<!-- my_template.html -->
{{hello}}
```

#### Explanation of code in the question

The `AuthorView` is the only one that will me mapped from the UrlConfs to receive requests, and it will call the other two views, depending on the type of request. If it is a HTTP POST request, `AuthorInterestFormView` will manage the request (read `post` method in `AuthorView`). If it is a HTTP GET request, `AuthorDetailView` will manage the request (read `get` method in `AuthorView`).

The only mixin in the code is [SingleObjectMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2/django/views/generic/detail.py). It is there to retrieve the `Author` instance for further manipulation.